# Cast a string toTimestampType in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with one column that I change to string through the function date_format.

```
lrPredictions.filter("label > 0").selectExpr("item_id", 
                                           "horizon_minutes", 
                                           "date_format(date_time, '1970-01-01 HH:mm:ss')" +  " AS datetime_from",
                                           "abs(prediction - label) AS error_abs_sum", // these are all the error_abs_sum, error_squ_sum and so on...
                                           "power(prediction - label,2) AS error_squ_sum", 
                                           "100 * abs(prediction - label) /  label AS error_per_sum", 
                                           "abs(last_value - label) AS delta_sum")
```

However I want to take that same column back to TimestampType as I need to dump the dataframe in a DB with a date column.

How can I do that?. I have not found any function or example in java.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what format the date is available, you can use below and specify the format in which you're providing string to get timestamp.

Note that I have imported types from Spark. This code is in Scala, but Java code should be similar.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val df = sc.parallelize(List("2018-08-11 11:44:50", "2019-09-11 11:20:00")).toDF
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.select(unix_timestamp(col("value"))cast(TimestampType))
```

If you look at schema of df2, it will be timestamp type

```
root
 |-- CAST(unix_timestamp(value, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) AS TIMESTAMP): timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This turned out to solve the problem. Complete instruction, assuming your column is named datetime_from is: predictionsToDump.withColumn("datetime_from", predictionsToDump.col("datetime_from").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (code is in scala but it shouldnt matter in this case):

```
tmp.createTempView("temp_3")
tmp.show
+-------------------+---+---+
|                 ts|  b|  c|
+-------------------+---+---+
|1970-01-01 12:00:00|0.3|0.4|
|2014-01-01 12:00:00|0.1|0.4|
|2019-01-03 15:30:05|0.2|0.5|
+-------------------+---+---+
spark.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp(ts) as ts FROM temp_3").show
+----------+
|        ts|
+----------+
|     43200|
|1388577600|
|1546529405|
+----------+
```